# What is the reasoning behind the design of std.complex?

Tags: d, phobos

```
unittest
{
  immutable float a = 1.1, b = 1.2;
  auto c1 = complex(a,b);
  auto r1 = c1 + c1;  //  error, not mutable
}
```

Which means that I can have `Complex!(immutable float)`, but I can never use its `opBinary` functions against another instance of `Complex!(immutable float)`.  So, why is std.complex implemented in such a way?

Here is the `opBinary`.  It calls the `opOpAssign`, which won't work with `immutable`, hence the error.

```
Complex!(CommonType!(T,R)) opBinary(string op, R)(Complex!R z) const
{
    alias typeof(return) C;
    auto w = C(this.re, this.im);
    return w.opOpAssign!(op)(z);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that it's a bug. Certainly, if it's not a bug, it's a bad design. But looking at the code for `opOpAssign` and how much of it there is, my guess would be that they were trying to avoid code duplication and forgot to take into account that what they were doing wouldn't work with `immutable`. I'd suggest that you [report it as a bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues).

Comment: on that note using opbinary directly and doing a single blanket `auto opOpAssign(string op, R)(R z){return (this=this.opBinary!(op)(z));}` would solve all of that

Comment: It seems that creating `immutable BigInt` is not possible either.  Is that a bug too?

Comment: @Arlen No idea. It's certainly worth an enhancement request. But it frequently takes extra work to make user-defined types work with `immutable`, and if the person defining a type doesn't specifically code for it, then there's a decent chance that it won't work. My guess is that Don just didn't think about `immutable` when he wrote `BitInt`, but I don't know.